# Using .dlls in my projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Hello,
                                                                                         Specs: VS 2010 C++ professional edition.

I have a project with some statistical functions that I want to test.
So I wrote a simple test console application which I added to the solution of the project with functions that I want to test.
Here is the detailed layout of my project:

Project **BASE**, contains classes with functions that are used in my statistical application called **ROC**. And then there is **roc_test**, simple console application that I want to use for testing of some functions in **ROC** application. Now, **ROC** is linked to **BASE** and **roc_test** has **ROC** as referenced project. My problem is that when I try to compile my test project **roc_test**, the compiler throws an error saying that my **roc_test** project is missing a .dll file that belongs to project **BASE**. **roc_test** however, is not directly linked to **BASE**.  I don't understand why it throws such a message and how I can fix it.                                                For the sake of clarity let me try to show the relationship in a different way.

**roc_test** function calls rocfit(..) function, which is part of **ROC.h**. **ROC.h**  using functions that are written in **DoubleMatrix.h**, which is part of a **BASE** project.
I hope I am being clear. 
P.S. There is no point in showing the code as the problem is not in the code but in the  linker settings.
Thanks for any help.

EDIT: My question is how do i get rid of the error? Do I also need to link my test project to the **BASE**? It's just doesn't make sense that I have to do it. It should be enough to link it to **ROC**. Am I right?

Comment: I think it's the bit around 'the compiler throws an error saying . . .'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not included in the same directory as the console app (or in the path), then you'll need to include BASE as the runtime can't resolve the dependancy on BASE by ROC.

Edit: Simply referencing ROC isn't enough; although there may be some build option that builds ROC and BASE and then links them into a single DLL; that could be worth investigating.

Also, instead of using a Console application, you might find it better in the long run at using unit tests.
This msdn article explains how to use vs2010 test projects with C++:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243171.aspx